# Running a JavaFX application on Mac

Tags: macos, javafx, javafx-8, javapackager

I've built a JavaFX application and am packaging it up natively. I currently have Windows and Linux running really well and want to do Mac next. Actually, I don't just want to see Mac running, I want to get onto the Mac App Store. I've seen some people reference that this IS possible, but I had some detailed questions (because Apple has very stringent requirements).

In the rules (https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/mac/) they mention:

> 2.24 Apps that use deprecated or optionally installed technologies (e.g., Java, Rosetta) will be rejected

I believe that the "Java" reference here is a version of Java that used to be packaged with OS X and if I package a JVM like how JavaFX does it, things are okay. Is this still correct?

> 2.31 Apps that are not sandboxed appropriately may be rejected

Is sandboxing even applicable to a JavaFX application? My app is going to save a file in the user's home area and also communicate with my server over the internet. Additionally, my app is going to have to call some command line utilities (arp, netstat) to get info that's unavailable to Java.

Am I going to be okay here?

> 6.1 Apps must comply with all terms and conditions explained in the OS X Human Interface Guidelines

This one has me a bit worried. In looking at the guidelines it seems that they want everything to look like a normal OS X application. But if I have a menu in my app (and I do) how is it going to blend in to the whole scheme of how OS X menues work?

Anything else I should know?